# C# Interface to create Optional property

Tags: c#, interface

I have Interface written in C# and is it already implemented by classes. Is it possible can i add one more property as optional in interface and without modifying the exiting implemented classes?

E.g

```
public interface IShape
{
    int area { get; }
}

public class FindWindow : IShape
{
    public int area
    {
        get
        {
            return 10;
        }
    }
}
```

In this FindWindow is already written. Is it possible can i add one Optional Property and not implementing in the existing class.

ie,

```
public interface IShape
{
    int area { get; }
    //optional
    //string WindowName{get;}
}

public class FindWindow : IShape
{
    public int area
    {
        get
        {
            return 10;
        }
    }

    //WindowName i am not implementing here
}

public class FindWindowName : IShape
{
    public int area
    {
        get { return 20; }
    }

    public string WindowName
    {
        get { return "Stack Overflow"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's useless if it's optional. No, you can't do this.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. I would disagree with this statement (of course I can be wrong). In a situation where you already have an interface that is implemented in a big number of classes and you need some prop to pass just because of couple of new classes has new behaviour it could be tedious to add that to every class just because you need that 1 prop injected because of those 1 or 2 classes. If it is just an empty prop that is only used by those classes without any chance of more classes with that behaviour then sure, it is useless. What would be cool to have is default implementation props or somth.

Comment: @MantasDaškevičius if you want default impls, look at `abstract`. Otherwise, why not make a sub-interface?

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Just wanted to state my opinion. TBH, yeah, I would just make and implement one more interface on that class and just check if resolved class implements it. In a sense... yeah... on the one hand it kind of beats the purpose of an interface

Answer (score 30):

There's no concept of optional members of an interface.

What you need here is to define two interfaces. One contains `area`, and the other contains `WindowName`. Something like this:

```
public interface IShape
{
    int area { get; }
}

public interface IFindWindow: IShape
{
    string WindowName { get; }
}
```

Then the implementing classes can choose to implement either `IShape` or `IFindWindow`.

At runtime you simply use the `is` operator to determine whether or not `IFindWindow` is implemented by the object at hand.

```
IShape shape = ...;
if (shape is IFindWindow)
    ....
```

And to actually use the more derived interface use the `as` operator:

```
IShape shape = ...;
IFindWindow findWindow = shape as IFindWindow;
if (findWindow != null)
    string windowName = findWindow.WindowName;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create a new interface that those shapes that wish to use the option would derive from instead:

```
public interface IWindowedShape : IShape
{
    string WindowName{get;}
}
```

And so, if you're passed an `IShape`, you can now attempt a cast to the `IWindowedShape` to be able to *access* this optional property.

```
public void DoStuff(IShape shape)
{
   var windowed = shape as IWindowedShape;
   string windowName = null;
   if(windowed!=null)
   {
      windowName = windowed.WindowName;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

No, this is not possible. If you derive from interface, you *must* define all its members in derived class.

To achieve what you want you may think about using `Abstract` classes.

Example of use case:

```
public abstract class Base {
    public abstract Name {get;set;} // MUST DEFINE IN DERIVED CLASS, LIKE INTERFACE

    public string Surname {get;set;} // JUST A SIMPLE PROPERTY OF A BASE CLASS
}
```

if on other hand you need destict separation, define multiple `interfaces`, with different ptoperties and derive from appropriate interface when needed.

Answer (score 3):

It is the nature of interfaces that you have to implement all of the provided methods and/or properties.

In your case, you could create a new, second interface, which inherits from the original interface:

```
public interface IShape
{
    int area { get; }
}

public interface IShapeEx : IShape
{
    string WindowName { get; }
}
```

Your new classes would implement `IShapeEx` while your "legacy classes" would still implement `IShape`.